# How to stop MS Project from changing durations when adding resources?

Tags: ms-project

I need to add 2 extra people to a certain task that currently has 4 resources assigned.
As soon as I add one, project automatically extends the duration of the task without reason.
I've tried everything I've read so far: Disabling calculations, changing task type, disabling effort driving task (both in options and in the task) and nothing works, project keeps extending the duration of this task.

I even tried changing to the original task duration manually after adding the new resources, but project doesn't reverts the task date to the old one.

Please, I really need help with this. I've had a lot of headaches working with this software but this one has me totally beaten.

Comment: I did not use that program for a long time, but I remember there was an option to choose from "fixed effort", "fixed duration" or "fixed something else". I guess you should choose the "fixed duration" property of the task, **before** adding the resources.

Comment: *"I've had a lot of headaches working with this software"* - welcome to the club  :). And welcome to ProjectManagement.SE

Answer (score 0):

The most common fix for the issue described is to set the ***Task Type*** to ***Fixed Duration*** prior to adding the new resources.

[image: fixed duration]

If this doesn't work for you, it's likely at least one of the resources you are trying to add has a calendar conflict with the task. Usually, you want the Calendar being used by the resources to be the same as the calendar being used by the project/task.

You can check what calendar is being used by the resource by looking at the ***Base Calendar*** field in the resource sheet. Example:

[image]